# Why does this code print 0223?

Tags: c++, c, for-loop, switch-statement

Why does case 2 get evaluated twice in this for loop?

```
for (int x = 0; x <4; x++)
{
    switch (x)
    {
        case 2: printf("%d", x);
        case 0: printf("%d", x);
        default: break;
        case 3: printf("%d", x);
    }
}
```

edit: I forgot to add that this is not a legitimate piece of code. Just something that came up in my friends job exam last week.

Comment: You want to add `break` at the end of each `case`. Otherwise it's not going to work as intended and hit every case until a `break` is found.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Case 2 doesn't get evaluated twice: it is evaluated exactly once. However, when you don't end a case with the `break` statement, instead of leaving the `switch`, execution continues to the next case.

In other words, when `x` is 2, execution jumps to `case 2` and call `printf("%d", x)` with x = 2. Then, execution falls through to case 0, and calls `printf("%d", x)` with x still equal to 2. Then, execution falls through to the `default` case, where it hits a `break` statement and finally leaves the `switch`.

Comment: So when x = 2, case 0 is also executed even thought the condition is not  satisfied?

Comment: In C, a `case` is not a condition that guards execution. It's more like a `goto` label.

Comment: @Ozymandias `case 0` is coded below `case 2`. Without a `break`, execution flow starting in `case 2` falls through to `case 0`. Swap the order of the cases, and you won't see `case 0` executed anymore when `x=2`, but you will see `case 2` executed when `x=0`

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't. There's no break on those cases. That's why it prints case 2 then case 0.